# How to create a subarray of NSArray using NSRange?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsrange, arrays

I have an Array with content. as usual it contain 20 objects. I want the same array split into 2 sections in Tableview.
I am trying to implement it with NSMake in current array. For example I need get in first tableview section 3 rows and second will contain all the rest (17 rows ).

```
switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return
            [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 8)] count];
            // in this line, it always takes from the first object in array, despite I told hime start from 3 (If I understand right, how to works NSMakeRange)
            break;
        case 1:
            return
            [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(9, 19)] count];
            // here my app is crashing with an error 
            //*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]: range {9, 19} extends beyond bounds [0 .. 19]'
        default:
            break;
    }
```

Does anyone can help me with that?

Comment: NSMakeRange's parameters are (location, length).  Perhaps you're thinking it's something else?

Comment: If you have a hardcoded range, why bother creating the subarray? Just return the hardcoded count for each section and avoid all of the overhead of creating an `NSRange` and a wasted `NSArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy I more or less asked the same question, he said he wants the actual objects.

Comment: @JoelFischer But he's not using the array except to get the count. That's silly. The count will always be the `length` value of the `NSRange`.

Comment: I know, if you look at the bottom of my answer I said that I wasn't sure what count was used for. He commented saying `I don't need to return count of array objects. section 1 should contain objects from 1 to 3 and section 2 should contain from 4 to 20.` I'm assuming, based on that, and the fact that he IS using subarrays that what he really wants is the objects. I'm guessing this is used in a tableview rows for various sections. If this is for the number of rows, you're right, he should just just use hardcoded counts.

Comment: @rmaddy  I need count these object per each section in method tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: @Anton Right. Since you need a count you should return a count. Since you are hardcoding the length parameter in `NSMakeRange`, why not just return that length directly? There is no point to creating a subarray just to return its count when you are hardcoding the length of the subarray. The hardcoded length and the resulting subarray count will always be equal.

Comment: @rmaddy maybe will be better to split this array with 2 arrays?

Comment: this question is gone. it either needs MAJOR rewriting or closing.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`NSMakeRange` is defined as `(startingIndex, length)`, not `(start, end)` which it seems like how you are trying to use it.

So if you need the first 3 objects, then the rest it would look like this:

```
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        // This returns objects 0-2 in the array
        return [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)];
    case 1:
        // This returns objects 3-20 in the array
        return [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 17)];
    default:
        break;
}
```

Edit: According to your comment, you are actually looking for the count to return in number of rows in section. Since you are using a fixed number of rows, you can just return the actual number within the case statement.

```
switch (section) {
    case 0:
        // This returns the count for objects 0-2 in the array
        return 3;
    case 1:
        // This returns the count for objects 3-20 in the array
        return 17;
    default:
        break;
}
```

You do not actually need to use `[subarrayWithRange]`, nor `NSMakeRange`. If you do need to at some point reference the actual array, you will get an NSIndexPath object which you can use to get the object from your array. You will need to use the section and row properties.

Edit: `NSRange` -> `NSMakeRange`

Comment: Hi Joel, So How I can do what I need? I am using count, because I need return numberOfRowsInSection:

Comment: @Anton see my updated answer. This is assuming you're looking to actually return an array.

Comment: in second session it always takes rows from 0. I don't need to return count of array objects. section 1 should contain objects from 1 to 3 and section 2 should contain from 4 to 20.

Comment: @Anton That should be easy enough to do, in that case, you should be able to easily modify my answer. Just make another case for `2`, add another return statement and modify the NSMakeRanges in the style of `(location, length)` as above, and you'll be set!

Comment: There's no point to any of this. Just return hardcoded counts.

Comment: @JoelFischer in this line return [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 17)]; it will show my array always from the first object. I have tried the same with NSIndexSet. Getting the same :(

Comment: This answers provide some good piece of information about `NSRange`, but I believe it misses the main problem of the OP. He clearly stated in the comments that he needs to return an `NSInteger` in `numberOfRowsInSection:` but the answer now returns an array. Also, as @rmaddy rightfully pointed out, the whole thing is useless, as I explain in my answer.

Comment: The first comment to this answer.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella The first comment was edited, or I'm an idiot. One  of the two.

Comment: @JoelFischer yes it was edited. It's not your fault, the OP is clearly very confused about the subject and that's why the unclear question. I was too quick in casting a downvote, if you edit the answer I'll be able (and happy) to retract it.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Edited my answer above

Comment: the question is more than 'confusing'

Comment: @JoelFischer great! The only thing which is possibly incorrect, even though is a sketchy implementation, is `array[indexPath.row]`. Since he wants to use the same array for every section, you would actually need some offset according to the section. +1 though

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Yeah, I caught that, and since it wasn't part of the original question, and I figured it would make him more confused, I just removed it.

Answer (score 5):

As others have noted you are using `NSRange` improperly.

It's definition is

```
typedef struct _NSRange {
      NSUInteger location;
      NSUInteger length;
} NSRange;
```

so the second parameter of the struct is the length of the range, not the location of last element as you apparently think.

---

That being said, what you are doing it's much more complicated than it should be.

What's the purpose of producing a subarray of a known length and then returning the length of the subarray itself? With this in mind:

```
return [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 8)] count];
```

should be (using `NSRange` properly)

```
return [[array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, 6)] count];
```

but it can actually be just

```
return 6;
```

or if the range length is a parameter

```
return length;
```

Again, there's no need in the world to slice an array and count. The length is known a priori.

---

So in the context of `UITableViewDataSource`, you have to

- return the count for each section in `-tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. Something like

  ```
  switch(section) {
      case 0: return 2;
      case 1: return 18;
  }
  ```
- return the actual objects in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Something like

  ```
  id object = nil;
  switch (indexPath.section) {
      case 0:
          object = self.objects[indexPath.row];
          break;
      case 1:
          object = self.objects[2 + indexPath.row];
          break;
  }
  ...
  ```

---

As an extra tip, I would advice using a different notation for building structs

```
NSMakeRange(0, 42)
```

can be written

```
(NSRange){ .location = 0, .length = 42 }
```

which is much more readable (and less error prone, especially when you are in doubt about the meaning of the parameters).

Even

```
(NSRange){ 0, 42 }
```

is acceptable. I think it's better (and shorter) than `NSMakeRange`, but it loses the benefits or readability.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have solve my issue

In my Fetcher class I did

```
_sectionOne = [news objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 3)]];
_sectionTwo = [news objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(3, 17)]];
```

then

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return [_sectionOne count];
            break;
        case 1:
            return [_sectionTwo count];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then in method cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
 switch (indexPath.section) {
        case 0:
            item = [_sectionOne objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        case 1:
            item = [_sectionTwo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
```

item - it's my NSObject with MVC

So It's working As I wanted :)

Thanks for all trying to help me.

Cheers